# UTM-30LX not detected on /dev/ttyACM(*) by Ubuntu

Tags: laser, urg-node, ros-kinetic, hokuyo-node, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to connect my UTM-30LX to ubuntu 16.04 running ROS kinetic using the urg_node. I have installed URG and I am following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingTheHokuyoNode
(for the Hokuyo_node as I could not find a tutorial for the urg_node). All I have done so far is connect the lidar to my computer through USB and power it. I see no mention on Hokuyos website of linux drivers. Whenever I type ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 ubuntu spits out ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyACM0': No such file or directory. I have run various commands and I've realised that ubuntu is not detecting the UTM-30LX at all, It registers no change on /dev whenever the usb is connected

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307740/utm-30lx-not-detected-on-/dev/ttyacm(*)-by-ubuntu/) by [wmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/38407/wmr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a trick I do when debugging USB connected devices. I save the output of `lsusb -vvv` to a file with the device connected and without the device connected. Then `diff` the two files to see the details of the device, if there is no difference then the USB device is not registered by the OS at all. The process is:

With the device unplugged:

```
lsusb -vvv > unconnected.txt
```

Then plug the device in and run:

```
lsusb -vvv > connected.txt
diff unconnected.txt connected.txt
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1